# Error when creating a new maven project with Spring tool suite (Could not resolve archetype)

Tags: spring, maven

I am trying to create a new maven project using spring tool suite version(3.1.0),however every time I try to choose any archetype and after filling the group id and artifact id in the wizard it start downloading a few minutes then I get the following error :

Error Details 
"**Could not resolve archetype org.appfuse.archetypes:appfuse-modular-spring:RELEASE from any of the           configured repositories.
    Could not resolve artifact org.appfuse.archetypes:appfuse-modular-spring:jar:RELEASE
    Missing org.appfuse.archetypes:appfuse-modular-spring:jar:RELEASE**"

Note : same error occurred with me when I tried to create a new maven project with Eclipse Juno that I have installed one day before along with  maven2eclipse plugin.It looks like I have something wrong with my maven repository or configuration !

software installed in my machine is :

- 64 bit spring tool suite (v 3.1.0)
- 64 bit OS(windows 7)
- 64 bit JDK 7
- Maven repository location : C:\Users\Ahmed Mamdouh.m2\repository

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.